# Rails Best_In_Place gem doesn't update Order table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I'm building a marketplace app. Sellers can list products to sell. I'm using best_in_place to allow sellers to enter a tracking number and shipping carrier name in their sales page.

I use best_in_place for another model as well and that works fine. For some reason the order table update doesn't seem to work. These are the errors I get:

```
NoMethodError in Orders#sales
undefined method `tracking' for nil:NilClass
```

The error points to the first line with best_in_place used below.

Here is my view - this shows a sellers listings and two columns to enter tracking and carrier name:

```
<div class="center">
  <h2>Sales History for <%= current_user.name %></h2>
</div>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <%= link_to 'Add New Listing', new_listing_path, class: "btn btn-link", data: {  no_turbolink: true } %>
<% end %>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th class="col-md-2">Image</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Item</th>
    <th class="col-md-1">Price</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Customer</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Date Sold</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Shipment Tracking #</th>
    <th class="col-md-1">Carrier (UPS, USPS, etc.)</th>
 </tr>

<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= image_tag order.listing.image.url(:thumb) %></td>
  <td><%= order.listing.name %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_currency(order.listing.price) %></td>
  <td><%= order.buyer.name %></td>
  <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%B %-d, %Y") %></td>
  <td><%= best_in_place @order, :tracking, :type => :input %></td>
  <td><%= best_in_place @order, :carrier, :type => :input %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Here is my controller's sales method and update method.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! 
  before_action :check_user, only: [:edit, :update]    

def sales
   @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
end

def update
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
end

def check_user
  if current_user.id != @seller && current_user.name != "admin admin"
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, you are not the seller of this listing"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to spell it all out and see if it works:

```
<%= best_in_place @order, :tracking, :type => :input, :path => {:controller => :sales, :action => :update, :id => order.id} %>
```

Edit:
I think the error is in your `each do`, try the below:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= image_tag order.listing.image.url(:thumb) %></td>
  <td><%= order.listing.name %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_currency(order.listing.price) %></td>
  <td><%= order.buyer.name %></td>
  <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%B %-d, %Y") %></td>
  <td><%= best_in_place order, :tracking, :type => :input %></td>
  <td><%= best_in_place order, :carrier, :type => :input %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Basically I just swapped `@order` for `order`...